How is Wald deriving this Gauge condition: $\partial^b\, \overline{\gamma}_{ab} = 0$?
R. Wald in Section#4.4 of his book General Relativity derives the EFE in the case of a weak gravitational field by taking the curved spacetime metric $g_{ab}$ to be a "small" perturbation $\gamma_{ab}$ to a flat Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$, i.e., $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + \gamma_{ab}$. Then he basically substitutes this into the original EFE for $g_{ab}$ with only linear terms in $\gamma_{ab}$.
On pg. 75, Eqn. (4.4.9) he writes down the gauge transformation: $\gamma_{ab}\mapsto\gamma_{ab} + 2\partial_{(a}\,\xi_{\,b)}$, where $\partial_a$ is the derivative operator arising from $\eta_{ab}$. I completely understood why this is a Gauge transformation. But in the next sentence he says "solving the equation $\partial^b\partial_b\xi_a = -\partial^b\, \overline{\gamma}_{ab}\ \ $ for $\xi^a$" ... and then he somehow obtains (4.4.11) the gauge condition: $\partial^b\, \overline{\gamma}_{ab} = 0$.

My question is what is exactly meant by "solving for $\xi^a$" and how did he even get the equation $\partial^b\partial_b\xi_a = -\partial^b\, \overline{\gamma}_{ab}\ \ $ in the first place ??
How does he obtain the gauge condition (4.4.11): $\partial^b\, \overline{\gamma}_{ab} = 0$ ?

Some detailed calculational steps would be much appreciated. TIA.

Briefly speaking, one chooses rather than derives a gauge-fixing condition (aka. a gauge), such that it intersects each gauge-orbit exactly once. The Lorenz/de Donder/harmonic gauge (4.4.11) is a popular choice.

ahh I see. This does answer my second question above. But what about my first question? I'm still unsure what is meant by the phrase "solving for $\xi^a$" in the equation $\partial^b\partial_b\xi_a = -\partial^b, \overline{\gamma}_{ab}\ \ $. How does one solve for $\xi^a$? Is this something I'm supposed to know before studying GR?

@math-physicist The idea used by Wald in this section is: you substitute a general field $\xi_a$ in the gauge transformation, then see what it has to be in order to simplify the equations. In doing that, you find that the $\xi_a$ that satisfies the equation gives rise to the given gauge condition.
